# Restrict File Visibility on Records?

Tags: permissions, sharing, chatter-file

I have users who need to have access to certain Accounts and upload files to those Accounts (Using the Chatter File/ContentDocument Object). The org is fairly locked down and some of the files that need to be attached to the record come from Executive level users and those files do not need to be visible to the lower level employees.

Is there any way to restrict the visibility of certain files on a record to certain users while still allowing other users to access the Account and upload files of their own?

It appears that despite the File sharing settings, any user that has access to the Account has access to the files attached to that Account?

Comment: I could be mistaken as Chatter isn't my area and things can change, but I believe if you create a separate chatter group for those who would have the executive level access you mention, files could be shared within that group associated with the Account which wouldn't be available to users who aren't members of the group. I don't believe they get attached to the Account, but instead to the feed. If I were confident this was accurate I'd post it as answer, but as I'm not, thus the reason it's a comment instead.

Comment: @crmprogdev, you're right and thanks for the comment. The tough part is that it's basically going to be needed on every Account so while I could have a "VIP" chatter group and share files within that group, they're wanting to access these files via related list on the record. It would be great if we could use the built in sharing that files has but the fact it's shared to a record overrides all other sharing settings for that file to grant access to anyone with access to the record. Rock/hard place.